# Can more than a single copy of a legendary be obtained in Dream Radar>

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

In Pokemon Dream Radar you can catch 3 Radar-specific legendary Pokemon.  You can also, depending on the game inserted in the actual DS System, capture Lugia, Ho-Oh and other game-specific legendaries.

I noticed there are simulations that are unlocked that are repeatable "captures" of the Radar-specific legendaries.  Does this mean they can be captured again?  In other words, what is the point of the alpha, beta, and gamma simulations if not to capture them multiple times?

Can Lugia, Ho-Oh, and other cartridge specific legendaries be captured more than once?

I am assuming that the only way to do this would be to delete the saved data for both Black/White V2 and Dream Radar, but aside from that, can they be captured more than once and transferred to have multiple copies of each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is no.

In order to obtain and transfer multiple copies of the legendary Pokemon from Dream Radar, you need to wipe both the Dream Radar and Black2/White2 save data.

Confirmed this myself.  Pretty unfortunate.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only way to get multiples of legendaries through Dream Radar is to wipe the save of the Dream Radar game. You shouldn't need to delete the saved data in B2/W2.

You'll likely have to delete the entire Dream Radar game, its save file, then download it again from the e-shop.

Comment: I was under the impression that only 1 of the legendaries was able to be transferred to B2/W2.  I'll have to give this a try later and find out.  If it is correct, you've got yourself an accepted answer.

Comment: @Mkalafut: The intersting part here is how the game remembers you transferred one already. If it just checks for the Pokemon's presence on the game, simply trading it away would do the trick. If it sets some software flag, though, you do have to wipe the save.